# is ioutil.ReadAll blocking my server?

Tags: asynchronous, go

I'm trying to write a server in Go, using the `net/http` package. I only have one route, and it's pretty simple. It downloads a file from S3 and returns it to the client:

```
response, err := http.Get("some S3 url")
if err != nil {
    return
}
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
w.Write(body)
```

Downloading the url myself takes about 0.25 seconds. So I start this server and send it 250 requests/sec. Initially I get responses back within 0.25 seconds. But that number keeps going up until it starts taking 45 seconds for a response. I'm running this on a 40 core machine, with `GOMAXPROCS=40`. I started wondering if somehow the downloads aren't happening in parallel.

But if I comment out this line:

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
```

And just return some garbage data of equal length, suddenly my server consistently responds in 0.25 seconds. Why is it faster after removing the `ReadAll`?

Comment: Fair enough, I will make those two changes. I don't think I'm saturating a network link though, because I can `curl` the S3 url while the server is working, and it still downloads for me in `0.25` seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things comes to mind:

1. You're not closing `response.Body` and the server is running out of FDs.
2. The garbage collector is being slow and you're running out of memory for reading so many files with `ReadAll`.
3. You're choking the networking because of #1.

Try something like this and see if it helps:

```
response, err := http.Get("some S3 url")
if err != nil {
    return
}
defer response.Body.Close()
_, err := io.Copy(w, response.Body)
```

Comment: @VladtheImpala glad to be of help, but yeah io.Copy is always the way to go for that kind of things.